# Highchart - Editing the tooltip date format content on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I have the chart displayed as follows[image]

How do i change ONLY the date format in the tooltip, to include year in it?

I am aware of the `formatter` that can be added to the tooltip property, but the current default tooltip is fine, just need to show the year too.

It is a datetime plot. where in I pass an array of UNIX datetime and value sets objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reformat dateTimeLabelFormats in your tooltip, even if you only want add the year.

```
tooltip: {
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            year: '%A, %b %e, %Y'
         },
         [otherparams]
}
```

Maybe it's not `year`, but I think it's the only way to reformat your tooltip.

Some doc : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.tooltip.dateTimeLabelFormats